# Changing resolution causes black screen

Tags: opensuse, display, resolution

I have a laptop with maximum supported resolution 2560x1440. Whenever I change the resolution, the display turns black. (The 20 second grace period is observed)

I'm using openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Here are the results of my tweaking.

| DE | Action | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KDE | Changing resolution | Breaks |
| KDE | Changing refresh rate | Breaks |
| GNOME | Changing resolution | Breaks |
| GNOME | Changing refresh rate | Works |
| Both | Changing other display configurations (Scaling, etc.) | Works |

Using Wayland and Xorg yields the same result.

Comment: More details are required. What kind of laptop is it (brand/model)? What kind of GPU is built in (e.g intel, amd, nvidia) and what model? What graphics driver and driver version? e.g. if it's an nvidia gpu, are you using the open-source nouveau driver or proprietary nvidia driver? Add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your  question. That will output a line line `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller...brand...model...`.  Then take the bus:device.func number at the start of that line (e.g. 01:00.0 from the line above) and use it with `lspci -v -k -s nn:nn.n` - add that to your question too.